# Creating a site in alfresco using open cmis extension

Tags: content-management-system, alfresco, opencmis

I want to create a alfresco site using open cmis extension. I researched and found an object type 'F:st:sites' and its properties like 'st:siteVisibility'  and 'st:sitePreset'. But I am not very sure that using this we can create a site in alfresco and I am not able to find any method for creating a site. It could be something like

```
  Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    properties.put(PropertyIds.NAME, "mySiteName");
    properties.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, "F:st:sites");
    properties.put("cmis:path", "/Sites");
    .
.
    properties.put("cmis:createdBy", date);
    properties.put("st:siteVisibility", ScriptSiteService.PUBLIC_SITE);

// TODO: add method for creating site with session object
```

Please reply as soon as possible.

Also, if there is any other way to create a site other than apache's Http api, Please share.

Thanks,
Smita

Answer (score 1):

as long as you don't post your use case, yourfull code & explain in in detail what tools you're using (Apache Chemistry/opencmis? apache's Http api?) you won't get the answer you like to get...

A Site is sth. like a extended folder & there will be an opportunity to create such a folder by using st:site type & adding the relevant properties, BUT:
afaik you won't be able to use this site via Alfresco Share because all SURF objects are not created if you create a site directly in the repo layer (explained here (but a little bit outdated if you use Alfresco 4): http://ecmstuff.blogspot.de/2011/02/creating-alfresco-share-sites-with.html).

Comment: Agreed, there is no way you can create a functional Share site using CMIS alone.

Comment: Link is broken, maybe it was the same as http://www.ixxus.com/blog201203creating-alfresco-share-sites-javascript/ ?